# Git: branching?

Tags: git, branch

I got a local script of which I want to have 2 version. So I went to the directory of the script and did this:

```
git init
git add myscript.py
git commit -m "initial"
git checkout -b test_branch
```

After that I opened the script in an editor and wrote "foobar" at the end of the file. Then I went back to console and wrote:

```
git checkout master
```

So basically I switched from my test_branch back to master. I opened the script and there was still the "foobar" at the end. I was expecting it not to appear since I wrote it into the file when I was in the test_branch?

Comment: You have to commit your changes to the script on your test branch, before you change back to master.

Comment: Did you add and commit the script before checkout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you `checkout` to `test_branch` and you do some changes there, then before you `checkout` your `master` branch, you first need to commit all the changes made to the `test_branch`.

So it would be like:

```
git init                      #initializing
git add myscript.py           #added a file, ready to commit
git commit -m "initial"       #initial commit made to master

git checkout -b test_branch   #created and checked out a new branch
git add myscript.py           #add a file, ready to commit to test_branch
git commit -m 'other version' #commit the changes made to test_branch
git checkout master           #checkout master again
```

Comment: now it works as expected, what a useful software :) I didn't add and commit to my test_branch.